# How to make Apache stop log some my Urls

Tags: php, apache, vhosts, setenvif

I have a Web Application.

All requests to my app will pass to Root/index.php.
Example:

```
1. http://myapp.com/?call=phpfile1.processSomething&param1=x&param2=y
2. http://myapp.com/?call=phpfile2.processSomethingElse
3. http://myapp.com/?call=phpfile3.methodXYZ...
```

And I have an other app (WindowServices), it will call some Urls in my WebApp (All day :v). When I open access.log, It like this:

```
[2018-08-07 12:23:43] "GET /?call=phpfile1.processSomething&module=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 16
[2018-08-07 12:23:43] "GET /?call=phpfile2.processSomethingElse&module=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 16
[2018-08-07 12:23:43] "GET /?call=phpfile1.processSomething&module=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 16
[2018-08-07 12:23:43] "GET /?call=phpfile1.processSomething&module=7 HTTP/1.1" 200 16
[2018-08-07 12:23:43] "GET /?call=phpfile2.processSomethingElse&module=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 16
[2018-08-07 12:23:43] "GET /?call=phpfile2.processSomethingElse&module=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 16
```

And...access.log file will be large file over times.

So, I don't want Apache loging Urls:

```
1./?call=phpfile1.processSomething
2./?call=phpfile2.processSomethingElse
```

I seted some config in vhost file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\MyFolderApp"
   <Directory "D:\MyFolderApp">
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
         Require all granted         
   </Directory>
   ServerName myapp.com
   SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/?call=phpfile1.processSomething" dontlog
   SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/?call=phpfile2.processSomethingElse" dontlog
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
   CustomLog "logs/myapp.com-access.log" common env=!dontlog
</VirtualHost>
```

But Apache still write log for these Urls!!!

So, Any one help me!!!
Thanks!

Comment: Your match strings in the `SetEnvIf` lines include some characters that need escaping: `?` -> `\?` and `.` -> `\.` If this doesn't work, try removing the `"` characters as well.

Comment: Thanks @Nick ! And I did do that. `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/\?call=phpfile1\.processSomething" dontlog`
But it doesn't work!

Comment: Have you tried printing out `Request_URI` to check it has the format/content you are matching?

Comment: I used this link to check: [link]https://regex101.com/[link] with RegEx: `^\/\?call=phpfile1\.processSomething`. Test string: `/?call=phpfile1.processSomething&module=5`. It's OK!

Comment: No, I meant what is the string you are matching against; i.e. print_r( Request_URI). If your regex is correct, then it must be your input.

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` doesn’t contain the `QUERY_STRING` only the path. The latter variable does, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nick and Tarun. I resolved my problem.
In my `.htaccess` file, I add some configs:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^automate/phpfile1/(.*) ?call=phpfile1. processSomething&module=$1
    RewriteRule ^automate/phpfile2/(.*) ?call=phpfile2.processSomethingElse&module=$1
</IfModule>
```

And in my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file, I set like below:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/automate/phpfile1/"  dontlog
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/automate/phpfile2/"  dontlog
CustomLog "logs/myapp.com-access.log" combined  env=!dontlog
```

So, apache doesn't logging Uris :D

Answer (score 0):

Here in your configuration `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/?call=phpfile1.processSomething" dontlog`, this line is in format

*SetEnvIf attribute regex env-variable*

So your regex is *"^/?call=phpfile1.processSomething"*, in which there are special characters like *'?'*. Escape these characters and change your regex to something like `^\/\?call=phpfile1\.processSomething(.*)`.

> Do remember to reload your apache configuration, reload or restart your apache server